# How to check if a binary tree is a valid BST if it contains duplicates or contains +/- infinity?

Tags: algorithm, tree

My solution to check if binary tree is a BST is as follow:

```
def is_BST(node):
  if node is None:
    return False

  stack = [(node, -float('inf'), float('inf')]
  while len(stack) > 0:
    node, lb, ub = stack.pop()
    if node.val <= lb or node.val >= ub:
      return False

    if node.left:
       stack.append((node.left, lb, node.val))
    if node.right:
       stack.append((node.right, node.val, ub))

  return True
```

But if the tree contains -inf or inf, or has duplicate values, my function won't work properly. How can I adjust it so that it works more generally?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `recursive` function that is more elegant, also using set:

```
set = {-float('inf'), float('inf')}
isValid = True


def BST(node):

if(node is None):
    return

if node.value in set:
    global isValid
    isValid = False
else:
    set.add(node.value)

    BST(node.left)
    BST(node.right)
```

Your code doesn't seem to work well:

```
node, lb, ub = stack.pop()
```

Here you are removing your `nodes`, you have to keep all the data for finding duplicates.